# Crowdrender Add-on cannot sync to render node

Tags: rendering, network

I have two PCs connected with LAN cables through a router. I have the crowdrender addon installed on both render nodes and logged in with my crowdrender account. Crowdrender recognizes the other PC with the correct name and IP address. But when I press "connect" I get the error message "sync failed". I have disabled the firewalls (eset internet security) on both PCs. I appreciate your help!

[image: sync failed screenshot]

Comment: what about the router's fire wall?

Comment: @MartyFouts I disabled it and tried again.... no success still :/

Comment: You'll probably need to go to the crowdrender forums for help, because you're problem is probably network related.